# Mutation with list of strings Variable "$_v0_data" got invalid value Graphql Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js, prisma

I have this simple mutation that works fine

```
    type Mutation {
    addJob(
        url: String!
        description: String!
        position: String!
        company: String!
        date: DateTime!
        tags: [String!]!
    ): Job
}
```

Mutation Resolver

```
    function addJob(parent, args, context, info) {

    console.log('Tags => ', args.tags)
    // const userId = getUserId(context)
    return context.db.mutation.createJob(
        {
            data: {
                position: args.position,
                componay: args.company,
                date: args.date,
                url: args.url,
                description: args.description,
                tags: args.tags
            }
        },
        info
    )
}
```

however, once I tried to put an array of strings(tags) as you see above I I can't get it to work and I got this error

```
Error: Variable "$_v0_data" got invalid value { ... , tags: ["devops", "aws"] }; Field "0" is not defined by type JobCreatetagsInput at value.tags.
```

If I assigned an empty array to tags in the mutation there is no problem, however if I put a single string value ["DevOps"] for example i get the error

Comment: please add the code for the mutation

Comment: @Peter Added it.

Comment: Did you change your mutation schema recently? Did you `prisma deploy`? It seems like the `type JobCreatetagsInput` is not expecting this `String` type.

Comment: @Elfayer No, it's not changed at all and if I tried Prisma deploy the schema is up to date, and about this is the JobCreatetagsInput , input JobCreatetagsInput { set: [String!] }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was in the resolver function apparently as I found [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1275) I have to assign the tags list within an object in the set argument like the code below

```
function addJob(parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.db.mutation.createJob(
        {
            data: {
                position: args.position,
                componay: args.company,
                date: args.date,
                url: args.url,
                description: args.description,
                tags: { set: args.tags }
            }
        },
        info
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, works as a charm is not clear about this in the doc.

Comment: @Merlyn007 glad it helped ^^